# No api proxy found for service "app_identity_service" when running GAE script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to run a custom stript to upload static files to a bucket.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append("/tools/google_appengine")
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
vendor.add('../libraries')

import cloudstorage as gcs

STATIC_DIR = '../dashboard/dist'

def main():
    bucket_path = ''.join('/' + app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
```

What I've been trying so far:
- initialize stubs manuaIlly

```
def initialize_service_apis():
    from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver

    from google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_main import ParseArguments
    args, option_dict = ParseArguments(sys.argv) # Otherwise the option_dict isn't populated.
    dev_appserver.SetupStubs('local', **option_dict)
```

(taken from https://blairconrad.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/automated-testing-using-app-engine-service-apis-and-a-memcaching-memoizer/)

But this gives me import error when importing `dev_appserver` lib.

Is there any way to resolve the issue ?
I need this script for an automatic deployment process.

Answer (score 1):

The `No api proxy found for service <blah>` error messages typically indicate attempts to use GAE standard env infrastructure (packages under `google.appengine` in your case) inside standalone scripts, which is not OK. See [GAE: AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338094/gae-assertionerror-no-api-proxy-found-for-service-datastore-v3).

You have 2 options:

- keep the code but make it execute **inside** a GAE app (as a request handler, for example), not as a standalone script
- drop GAE libraries and switch to libraries designed to be used from standalone scrips. In your case you're looking for [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries). You may also need to adjust [access control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists) to the respective GAE app bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `dev_appserver.SetupStubs()`, but I received this same error message while running unit tests in a testbed. In that environment, you have to explicitly enable stubs for any services you wish to test (see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting)).

In particular, initializing the app identity stub solved my problem:

```
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

t = testbed.Testbed()
t.init_app_identity_stub()
```