# GAE: AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v3"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm writing simple to code to access dev server. Both dev server and datastore emulated have been started locally.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Account(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

acc = Account(name=u"test").put()
print(acc)
```

Error:

```
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v3"
```

I tried to set: `export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8760` . It does not help.

```
$ dev_appserver.py  ./app.yaml 
WARNING  2017-02-20 06:40:23,130 application_configuration.py:176] The "python" runtime specified in "./app.yaml" is not supported - the "python27" runtime will be used instead. A description of the differences between the two can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27
INFO     2017-02-20 06:40:23,131 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-02-20 06:40:23,508 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53755
INFO     2017-02-20 06:40:23,514 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-02-20 06:40:23,517 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE app code cannot run as a **standalone** python app, it can only run **inside a GAE app** which runs inside your dev server. Typically as part of a handler code, triggered via http requests to the dev server.

You need to put that code inside one of your app handlers. For example inside the `get()` method of the `MainPage` handler from [`main.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart#mainpy) in the  [Quickstart for Python App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart) (actually it'd be better in a `post()` method since your code is writing to the datastore).

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate datastore using standalone scripts? I have large dataset in mongodb locally. I need to port it to local datastore emulator, check data integrity, then upload to cloud datastore. It'll be better if I can reuse the ndb models.

Comment: Not using `ndb`, which is only available inside GAE apps. But yes, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries.