# import cloudstorage, ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I would like to use [Google Cloud Storage Client Library Functions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions).

For that I have to import the `cloudstorag`. To get the `cloudstorage` I download [Google Cloud Storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage).

I try to import cloudstorage using `python -c "import cloudstorage"`. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "cloudstorage/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api_utils import RetryParams
  File "cloudstorage/api_utils.py", line 45, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import app_identity
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import cloudstorage, SyntaxError: invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560171/import-cloudstorage-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute `python -c "import cloudstorage"` you're attempting to run a standalone application. But the GCS library you're trying to use is for a (standard environment) GAE application, which cannot be executed as a standalone app, it needs to run in a GAE sandbox (locally that's `dev_appserver.py`). See [GAE: AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338094/gae-assertionerror-no-api-proxy-found-for-service-datastore-v3/42347827#42347827).

And the library needs to be installed inside your GAE app, see [Copying a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library).

If you're not developing a standard env GAE app and indeed you want to write a standalone one, you're not looking at the right documentation. You need to use a different library than the GAE-specific one(s). See  [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this lines, which will add the path of the sdk tools:

```
import pkgutil
import google

google.__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(google.__path__, google.__name__)
```

For unittesting, it could be useful to run in standalone mode.

Comment: As I can guess this answer is not related to the question.

Comment: Now, it should be more clear that it is related to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gcloud is not installed on your system.

> pip install --upgrade gcloud
>
> pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

Comment: Both `gcloud` and `google-api-python-client` are installed. I still get the same error.

Comment: Within the same installation? That is, you are executing `python -c "import cloudstorage"` while pip might be a pip3 installation and installing in python3.

Comment: The installations are in a virtualenv called `ve_python2 `. `python --version Python 2.7.14` and `pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from ve_python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`. There are no other pythons in `ve_python2/lib`.